# how do I access a previously created from a page on a different page

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a modal i created that shows a team member's info. I want this same modal to be linked to the team members' names on a differnt page so that the same info pops up when the name is clicked. the modal works fine in the team page, but I just can't seem to figure out how to have the  same modal pop up on the other page. I asked ChatGPT, and it gave me a bunch of code which did not work and I think I messed up even my previously written code. PLS HELP (sidenote: this is my first time building a website so I am very new at this). I am using django to build the website.

team.html (original modal)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Green Team - Our Team{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Our Team{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            {% for team_member in team_members %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="team-member-card team-card-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teamMemberModal{{ team_member.id }}">
                        <div class="profile-picture profile-picture center">
                            <img src="{{ team_member.image.url }}" alt="{{ team_member.name }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="team-member-info">
                            <h3 class="name">
                              {% if team_member.id in team_member_pks %}
                                <a href="#" class="author-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teamMemberModal{{ team_member.id }}">
                            {{ team_member.name }}
                                </a>
                              {% else %}
                                {{ team_member.name }}
                              {% endif %}
                            </h3>
                            <p class="position">{{ team_member.position }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Team Member Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="teamMemberModal{{ team_member.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="teamMemberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content text-center">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="teamMemberModalLabel">{{ team_member.name }}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                                <div class="profile-picture profile-picture center">
                                    <img src="{{ team_member.image.url }}" alt="{{ team_member.name }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="team-member-info">
                                    <p class="position ">{{ team_member.position }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bio">
                                    {{ team_member.bio }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

blog.html (where I want the modal to show up)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Green Team - Blog{% endblock %}

{% block heading %}Green Team Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            {% for post in blog_posts %}
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                    <div class="blog-post">
                        <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk %}">
                            <div class="blog-post-img-container">
                                <img src="{{ post.cover_photo.url }}" alt="Cover Photo" class="blog-post-img">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% if post.author and post.other_author %}
                            <p class="author-name">
                                {% if post.author.pk in team_member_pks %}
                                    <a href="#" class="author-link" data-team-member-pk="{{ post.author.pk }}">{{ post.author }}</a>, {{ post.other_author }}
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ post.author }}, {{ post.other_author }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>
                        {% elif post.author %}
                            <p class="author-name">
                                {% if post.author.pk in team_member_pks %}
                                    <a href="#" class="author-link" data-team-member-pk="{{ post.author.pk }}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ post.author }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>
                        {% elif post.other_author %}
                            <p class="author-name">{{ post.other_author }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                            <p class="author-name">Anonymous</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        <a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk %}">
                            <h3 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
                        <a/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                    </div><div class="row">
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Hidden div to store the team member details -->
    <div id="teamMemberDetails" style="display: none;">
        {% for team_member in team_members %}
            <div class="team-member-info" data-team-member-pk="{{ team_member.pk }}">
                <h5 class="modal-title">{{ team_member.name }}</h5>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="profile-picture">
                        <img src="{{ team_member.image.url }}" alt="{{ team_member.name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-member-info">
                        <p class="position">{{ team_member.position }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bio">
                        {{ team_member.bio }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <!-- Team Member Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="teamMemberModal{{ team_member.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="teamMemberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content text-center">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="teamMemberModalLabel">{{ team_member.name }}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                                <div class="profile-picture profile-picture center">
                                    <img src="{{ team_member.image.url }}" alt="{{ team_member.name }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="team-member-info">
                                    <p class="position ">{{ team_member.position }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bio">
                                    {{ team_member.bio }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".author-link", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var teamMemberPK = $(this).data("team-member-pk");
            var teamMemberInfo = $(".team-member-info[data-team-member-pk='" + teamMemberPK + "']");
            var teamMemberName = teamMemberInfo.find(".modal-title").text();
            var teamMemberProfilePicture = teamMemberInfo.find(".modal-body .profile-picture img").attr("src");
            var teamMemberPosition = teamMemberInfo.find(".modal-body .team-member-info .position").text();
            var teamMemberBio = teamMemberInfo.find(".modal-body .bio").html();

            $("#teamMemberModalLabel").text(teamMemberName);
            $("#teamMemberProfilePicture").attr("src", teamMemberProfilePicture);
            $("#teamMemberPosition").text(teamMemberPosition);
            $("#teamMemberBio").html(teamMemberBio);

            $("#teamMemberModal").modal("show");
        });
        
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```